# What does the -= operator do?

Tags: objective-c, ios

What does the expression `-=` do?

I spent the last hour trying to fix a bug which ended up including -= in itself:

```
[self.myArray objectAtIndex:myButton.tag -= 1];
```

I'm not sure what that expression does, is it supposed to be similar to `+=`?

The truly mystifying part is if I NSLog() it, it borks my results:

```
NSLog(@"data with -=: %@", [self.myArray objectAtIndex:((UIButton *)sender).tag -= 1]);
```

When I comment just that line out, it works like it should. if I un-comment that line, I can't get the index location I want. I'm not 100% sure what it does to my array, but there is no reason that I can think of that when I just log it, that it would effect other parts of the code.

Comment: `x-=1` is equivalent to `x=x-1`

Comment: Your `]]` in the first example are not balanced.

Comment: `-=` *alters* the expression on the left and returns the new value, so that's why logging it changes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explained:

```
[self.myArray objectAtIndex:myButton.tag -= 1];
```

The `-=` operator `lvalue -= rvalue` is interpreted as `lvalue = lvalue - rvalue`. So, here your code can be written as:

```
[self.myArray objectAtIndex:myButton.tag = myButton.tag - 1];
```

An assignment statement (`=`), in turn, evaluates to its left side, so after decreasing `myButton.tag` by one, it will be passed to `objectAtIndex:` as if it was:

```
myButton.tag = myButton.tag - 1;
[self.myArray objectAtIndex:myButton.tag]; // here myButton.tag is already decreased by one
```

Comment: d'oh! is the assignment aspect. because in the nslog line of code, i'm reassigning the button.tag (say 5) value to - 1, then later i'm taking the new tag value of 4 and getting 1 less, which is 3 when i still wanted index 4. also, i guess i didn't realize you could reassign a value in a nslog stmt. =/ but i do see how it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

-= 1 is an assignment operation.

```
x -= 1;
```

Is like saying

```
x = x - 1;
```

so if you do (in pseudocode)

```
print(x = x - 1);
```

you can see you've changed x then printed it.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure everyone has had this problem at one time or another, especially when your mind is somewhere else.

First, all the other answers explain well what the operator `-=` does.

the reason your program borked when you put the log statement in is because you have decremented the target (`tag`) twice.

```
NSLog(@"data with -=: %@", [self.myArray objectAtIndex:((UIButton *)sender).tag -= 1]);  // this decrements that target the first time
[self.myArray objectAtIndex:myButton.tag -= 1]]; // this also decrements the target the second time
```

You should either do it this way

```
NSLog(@"data with -=: %@", [self.myArray objectAtIndex:((UIButton *)sender).tag]);  // this logs the value before the decrement
[self.myArray objectAtIndex:myButton.tag -= 1]]; // this decrements the target once
```

or this way

```
[self.myArray objectAtIndex:myButton.tag -= 1]]; // this decrements the target once
NSLog(@"data with -=: %@", [self.myArray objectAtIndex:((UIButton *)sender).tag]);  // this logs the value after the decrement
```

You might also be interested in the ++ and -- operators for incrementing and decrementing by 1. Read up on these to avoid using them incorrectly! In your case you could have done this:

```
[self.myArray objectAtIndex:--myButton.tag]]; // this decrements the target before using it as an index
```

But not this:

```
[self.myArray objectAtIndex:myButton.tag--]]; // this decrements the target after using it as an index
```

All very fun when you have been staring at your code late into the night.